# how to implement custom theme in magento 1.9

Tags: magento, customization

i am new in magento can anyone tell me nice and easy way to implement custim theme (Css\html) in magento 1.9.you can recomend free pdf which explain all the steps.

thanks in advance

Comment: Magento support would probably the best place to start.

Comment: Please do some effort from your side before asking a question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to youtube.com and type: install magento theme

you may also check out the videos of LevelUpTuts for more information on the magento theme directory structure etc.

Hope this helps.